# Quarkus dev postgresql container not shutting down with quarkus

Tags: postgresql, docker, quarkus, testcontainers

Quarkus version 2.16.7.Final. Datasource is Postgresql:12.4. Everything is default wrt dev services except the below settings:

```
    datasource:
      db-kind: postgresql
      devservices:
        image-name: artifactory.{"image-name"}/postgres:12.4
        port: 5000
```

I run the app using `mvn quarkus:dev`. When I shutdown or kill the server the Postgresql container continues to run (It used to shutdown cleanly along with the server before). I have to manually stop the container every time I want to start the server again.

Keycloack and ryuk containers are shutting down with server but the postgres container staying alive.

I tried to set testcontainers.reuse.enable=false but it doesn't help.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, can you please open an issue at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues? Thanks

Comment: did you by any chance open a bug? i am also facing this issue and wonder if there's a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34294 helped me. However, I still have no idea why it only occurs with the Postgres container.